# Having trouble displaying each loop result on different objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

Hi I was trying to create a jquery script where I can generate and add a class id by combining the current class plus the iterated result on the `each` function of jquery now the problem is the it does add the current class plus the number but the result looks like this 
[image: firebugresult]

Which I had in mind was something like this

```
   <a><p class="lbls chs0">1000</p></a>
   <a><p class="lbls chs1">4000</p></a>
   <a><p class="lbls chs2">6000</p></a>
```

is this possible?

This is what i have tried so far

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#qs").find(".chs").each(function(i,obj){
             $(".chs").addClass("chs"+i);
        });

  });
```

I'm new to jquery so I dont have that much knowledge on jquery any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to using `this` instead of `$(".chs")`

```
$("#qs").find(".chs").each(function(i,obj){
      $(this).removeClass("chs");  //Remove class .chs
      $(this).addClass("chs"+i);  //Add new class .chs+i
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jkofum1d/2/)**

Comment: Hi as I have mentioned above I'm new to jquery your given script worked but why did it worked when I used `this` instead of `$(".chs")`? is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Yes, If you write `.chs` then it will take first matching class and If you write `this` then it will take current object.

Comment: oh I see thanks that helped me much.. I'll accept this answer as soon as 7 minutes is over SO wont let me accept it right away thanks for explaining the difference between the two :)